# What does Infura do for contracts?

Tags: truffle, remix, infura

I am a bit confused by how some contracts can be launched with Remix (I presume without Infura), whereas if I launch contracts via truffle then I need to connect to Infura. Is there a simple explanation of:

- what Infura does?
- whether Remix uses Infura in the background?
- whether truffle based development always needs infura to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Infura is a gateway to enable access to some Ethereum networks.

Remix may work with a simulated blockchain or be attached to a real blockchain network. For example, you can use Remix linked to Metamask. Your Metamask may point to an Infura gateway or not. You can use Metamask to point to a permissioned blockchain network for example. You will probably use another gateway (not Infura) to that.

Similar to Remix, Truffle may work with a simulated network or be configured to a real blockchain network.